# PDO Method some issue with my code

Tags: php, pdo

Hi i am using a PDO wrap object

```
 https://github.com/Xeoncross/DByte/blob/master/example.php
```

having some issue with Updates features.
This is their defined function for update

```
static function update($table, $data, $value, $column)
{
    $keys = implode('`=?,`', array_keys($data));
    if($statement = DB::query(
        "UPDATE`$table`SET`$keys`=? WHERE`$column`=?",
        array_values($data + array($value))
    ))
        return $statement->rowCount();
}
```

My function to update

```
public function update_users($user_id, $user_name, $user_email, $user_role, $user_phone){

        $user_data = array(
        'user_name' => $user_name,
        'user_email' => $user_email,
        'user_pass' => $user_pass,
        'user_role' => $user_role,
        'user_phone' => $user_phone,
        );


        $result = DB::update('users', $user_data, $user_id);



}
```

This is not working Error i am getting is,

```
 Warning: Missing argument 4 for DB::update(), called in \XXXClass.php on line 47 and defined in XXXX\Application\inc\DB.php on line 120
```

Comment: Well, `DB::update` requires 4 parameters, and you are passing it 3. I don't see what's so hard to understand.

Comment: can you please let me know what i have to pass as 3rd parameter? i am bit confused..

Comment: You need to pass the column name for the value...`update($table, $data, $value, $column)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass in the column name (4th argument of the method):

```
$result = DB::update('users', $user_data, $user_id, 'user_id'); // I presume `user_id` is the name of that column
```

Also it doesnt hurt to place spaces between SQL keywords and column/table names:

```
"UPDATE `$table` SET `$keys`=? WHERE `$column`=?"
```